# Apache 2.4.17 64 Bit installer for solaris 10

Tags: apache, installation, solaris, bit

Does any one has Apache 2.4.17    64 bit installer for Solaris 10 /11.

or does any one have steps to compile apache 2.4.17 for 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

Solaris 10 is quite old these days, but for Solaris 11 then simply do as root or other privileged superuser:

```
pkg install web/server/apache-24
```

This will at the time of writing give you Apache Web Server 2.4.16, 64-bit.
Is it important for you that it is v2.4.17 ?